# How to connect a whole-house battery?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, battery, inverter

I've been curious about installing a small home battery (4 - 7 kWh) to take advantage of time-of-use (TOU) billing. The idea is that the battery charges from the grid off-peak and then the home switches to battery power as soon as peak period kicks in, and then if the load from the home is too much (either power or capacity) during the peak period, it supplements with power from the grid.

I'm not planning on actually doing the install myself, but I am curious how it's done and what steps are involved. Almost all online resources I have found describe doing this for primarily off-grid applications (RVs, boats, cabins). I did find a few videos but that shows when paired with a solar installation. I'm located in North America.

Does anyone know of websites or videos that demonstrate the installation process of whole-home battery systems?

Comment: Are you looking at an "all in one" system like a Tesla Powerwall, or something that's designed as an "add on" battery pack for a solar inverter?

Comment: Vermont utility does online battery storage as a program to aid with peaking. They give you a credit if you let them pull from your battery at peak times. The view is from 10,000 ft (and shows (optional) solar panels.) They push Powerwall, but have a "bring your own device" program that is more open. https://greenmountainpower.com/rebates-programs/home-energy-storage/powerwall/

Comment: @Ecnerwal That's a cool program in Vermont! That sounds kinda like the original idea they had for EV to grid applications. 

I guess you could say I'm looking for a Tesla Powerwall but without the solar and lower capacity. I use relatively little power and only need it to power 5-6 hrs / day. Looking at something like https://www.mangopower.com/